# Libraries and "My PC" in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer

I have a laptop which is running Windows 8.1 64bit. When opening Windows Explorer and enabling the option to show the libraries under the section "My PC", The screen looks like this:

[image]

*Translation:
Deze pc = my pc,
Bibliotheken = libraries*

On the most upper section of the Windows Explorer, you see all my libraries, such as my pictures, desktop items, documents, downloads, music and video's.

In the section from the libraries, you see those same folders again, my pictures, documents, music and video's.

Is it possible to delete those items from the "My PC" view? Because theyre showing double now.

Comment: Make sure system is virus free. so update the antivirus and do full scan.

Comment: @vembutech What does that have to do with this tweak?....

Comment: If you already have antivirus then its very simple to update antivirus to latest version. If not just install antivirus and update to latest version. Do full scan after updated.

Comment: @vembutech Yes, i've got  a virus scanner on my computer, why should I scan my computer when there's nothing wrong with it?...

Comment: keep one backup on all the files inside libraries such as my pictures, documents, music and video's etc., on any free volumes. Restore the libraries by simple right click on libraries -> click 'Restore Default libraries' .

Comment: @vembutech bro i cant understand one point why should user scan for default folders which was already clean,its little puzzling for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove it easily by modifying registry

1)Open notepad

2)Copy the following script and save it as sample.reg

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}]
"DescriptionID"=-

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}]
"DescriptionID"=-

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{031e4825-7b94-4dc3-b131-e946b44c8dd5}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{031e4825-7b94-4dc3-b131-e946b44c8dd5}]
```

3)Execute the registry file

hope it will resolve your problem

Comment: Thanks man, but what does this actually do? Can i Edit the list myself when going to that registry folder?

Comment: @Bas yep u could manually add it ,but for safer side u could execute the registry which is an easy job

Comment: It might seem stupid, but where do I see the list of items then? When I open the following location which is in your answer in my registry, all i see is numbers.

Comment: @bas for safe stuff you could save it as reg file and execute it,since its internal stuff,altering the number was little tedious task

Comment: What do you mean?